# How to pass data from TimePicker and Editor to a label in Xamarin Form?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page with a button, a TimePicker, and an Entry. I want to pass texts from Timepicker and Editor to labels by pressing that button (Add New Item button). How can I do that?

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MReport.TabbedMainPage">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <ContentPage Title="New Report" IconImageSource="NewReport.png" BackgroundImageSource="blue_windows.jpg">
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollView>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label x:Name="lbl01" />
                        <Label x:Name="lbl02"/>
                        <TimePicker HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Editor x:Name="editor_value" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="200" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Add New Item" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            </Grid>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Send Report" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Report History" IconImageSource="History.png" BackgroundImageSource="blue_windows.jpg" />
    <ContentPage Title="Messages" IconImageSource="Message.png" BackgroundImageSource="blue_windows.jpg"/>

</TabbedPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is pretty basic event handling - I'd suggest you spend some time reading the docs and looking at the sample apps if this is causing you problems

```
protected void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    lbl01.Text = editor_value.Text;

    // you need to assign an x:Name to your picker for this to work
    lbl02.Text = time_picker.Time.ToString();
}
```

Comment: When I use this method for returning data from popup into main page, I cannot.

Comment: your question shows the Label and other controls all on the same page, so my answer is based on that.  If that is not the scenario you need help with then you post the actual code you're using.  I also posted a comment on the question you asked yesterday which you never replied to, so I have to assume you figured out that problem.

Comment: I'm trying to solve that problem now. But I couldn't find any good related video on youtube about xct to solve my problem

Comment: `lbl01.Text = editor_value.Text;` returns compiler error in `editor_value` section but it runs successfully.